# Loading large mysql output into a variable to write to file

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code i have to write my file

```
<?
$date = date(F jS, Y g:i:s a);
$filename = "$date.csv";
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$data = "";
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

The data that i need to write, consists of the output from a mysql query, shown here

```
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['productid']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['user_id']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['category_id']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'><input type=text value=\"" . nl2br( $row['producttitle']) . "\"></td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['item_counter_style']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['Quantity']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['payment_gateway']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'><div id=ddesc>" . nl2br( $row['detailed_descrip']) . "</div></td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['selling_method']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['min_bid_amount']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['bidincrement']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_cost']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['who_pay_shipping']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_route']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['duration']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['currency']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['reserve_price']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['quick_buy_price']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['bid_starting_date']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['start_delay']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['status']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture1']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture2']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture3']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture4']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture5']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture6']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture7']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture8']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['payment_name']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['quantity_sold']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['clicks']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['expire_date']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['payment_id']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['size_of_quantity']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['tax']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sniper']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['no_of_repost']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sale_price']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['s_repost']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shop']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['relisted']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['or_price']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['return_pol']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['timetoadd']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['special']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['discount']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['bonus']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['totbid']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['freebids']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['autobidder']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_cost']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_item_number']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_shipping_cost']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_notes']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_cost_a']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_cost_c']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['Auction_ID']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'><a href=edit.php?productid={$row['productid']}>Edit</a></td><td><a href=delete.php?productid={$row['productid']}>Delete</a></td> "; 
echo "<td><input type=submit class=clone value=clone></td></tr>\r\n";
echo "</tr>";
```

How do i get all of that (above) into $data, to write to my file?

Comment: Want do you want in the file ? HTML ? Or some kind of CSV ? (as the file's name would indicate)

Comment: Hm, yeah, if you want CSV then you'll want to modify what you're outputting accordingly - but either way, you'll want to do something like concatenating to the $data variable like I've shown below.

Comment: @Dav : if he want some "real" CSV file, I'd recommend to try using http://php.net/fputcsv which should take care of delimiters (and escaping them if they are present within the data), instead of doing brute-concatenations

Answer (score 2):

Replace all of those `echo`'s with `$data .=` and you should be good to go. (Of course, you'll need to put the `fwrite()` and `fclose()` calls *after* this).

```
<?
$date = date(F jS, Y g:i:s a);
$filename = "$date.csv";
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$data = "";

$data .= "<tr>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['productid']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['user_id']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['category_id']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'><input type=text value=\"" . nl2br( $row['producttitle']) . "\"></td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['item_counter_style']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['Quantity']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['payment_gateway']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'><div id=ddesc>" . nl2br( $row['detailed_descrip']) . "</div></td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['selling_method']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['min_bid_amount']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['bidincrement']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_cost']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['who_pay_shipping']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_route']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['duration']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['currency']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['reserve_price']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['quick_buy_price']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['bid_starting_date']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['start_delay']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['status']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture1']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture2']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture3']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture4']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture5']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture6']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture7']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['picture8']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['payment_name']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['quantity_sold']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['clicks']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['expire_date']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['payment_id']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['size_of_quantity']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['tax']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sniper']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['no_of_repost']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['sale_price']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['s_repost']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shop']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['relisted']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['or_price']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['return_pol']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['timetoadd']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['special']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['discount']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['bonus']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['totbid']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['freebids']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['autobidder']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_cost']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_item_number']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_shipping_cost']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['supplier_notes']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_cost_a']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['shipping_cost_c']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['Auction_ID']) . "</td>";  
$data .= "<td valign='top'><a href=edit.php?productid={$row['productid']}>Edit</a></td><td><a href=delete.php?productid={$row['productid']}>Delete</a></td> "; 
$data .= "<td><input type=submit class=clone value=clone></td></tr>\r\n";
$data .= "</tr>";

fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
?>
```